# Headlamp Bulb for Porsche Boxster 986 2000

Tags: headlight, porsche

Are the bulbs for the main beam and dipped beam the same, as in one bulb does both or are they different?

When searching online at a couple of bulb websites, specifying either main or dipped seems to return the same list of H7 bulbs which look like main beam bulbs to me.

I need a single, dipped.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm only seeing the H7 listed for either high beam or low. The easiest way to ensure you're getting what you need is to take the old bulb out and look at the bulb itself. It will be marked on the back as to the bulb model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same bulb can be used in both head and dipped, what happens is that the bulb filament is positioned precisely within the curved reflector to give the required beam pattern, so the same bulb either does a longer beam pattern for main or a shorter lower one for dipped.

Went to amazon for a laugh just to check and it says they are correct for your porsche... see

[https://www.amazon.com/Philips-Standard-Halogen-Replacement-Headlight/dp/B00Y9VWL1M/ref=au_as_r?_encoding=UTF8&Make=Porsche%7C2&Model=Boxster%7C18&Year=2000%7C2000&ie=UTF8&n=15684181&newVehicle=1&s=automotive&vehicleId=1&vehicleType=automotive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00Y9VWL1M)